# Aggregating lists stored as json in sqlite3

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Kittens (
  k_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  human_name text,
  tags json
);
```

With this data

```
INSERT INTO Kittens (human_name, tags) VALUES ("Charles",'["fiendish", "fluffy", "quiet", "discerning", "catlike"]');
INSERT INTO Kittens (human_name, tags) VALUES ("Tails",'["fluffy", "loud","catlike"]');
INSERT INTO Kittens (human_name, tags) VALUES ("Mittens",'["fluffy","regal","catlike"]');
```

I'd like to aggregate the common kitten tags, and I believe this requires the json_group_array function, which I've read about here:

- https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jarray
- http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/json-group-array-td87148.html

However, this doesn't seem to be unrolling or aggregating the tags as I would expect, just list the lists consecutively.

```
sqlite> select json_group_array(tags) from Kittens;
["[\"fiendish\", \"fluffy\", \"quiet\", \"discerning\", \"catlike\"]","[\"fluffy\", \"loud\",\"catlike\"]","[\"fluffy\",\"regal\",\"catlike\"]"]
```

Any guidance on what this query should look like?  Seeking something more like:

```
tag_array

catlike
catlike
catlike
discerning
fiendish
fluffy
fluffy
fluffy   
loud 
quiet 
regal
```

And ultimately, with an aggregation:

```
tag_array  count(*)
fluffy     3
catlike    3
fiendish   1
discerning 1
loud       1
regal      1
quiet      1
```

Comment: Try my answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_group_array()` constructs an array from its elements; to extract values from an array, use [`json_each()`](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach):

```
SELECT tag, count(*)
FROM (SELECT j.value AS tag
      FROM Kittens
      CROSS JOIN json_each(Kittens.tags) AS j)
GROUP BY tag;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Concise and perfect.

Comment: This is awesome, but a tiny bit slow.  Any chance you know if there's syntax to index the json_each?  CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tag_json_index
ON Kittens(json_each(Kittens.tags));
   ...> Error: no such function: json_each

Comment: json_each() is a [table-valued function](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#table_valued_functions). An index would have to be implemented by the virtual table module.

Comment: A relational database works best when you store the data relationally.